# Capture webcam stream with overlapped image

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Can capture the live stream of webcam using below code but it does not contain the overlapped image how can capture with overlapped image

> html

```
      <div id="vid-controls">
      <video id="vid-show" autoplay style="z-index: -1;position: fixed;"></video>
      <img src="https://mockuphone.com/static/images/devices/samsung-galaxys4-black-portrait.png" style="z-index: 1000">
      <input id="vid-take" type="button" value="Take Photo"/>
      <div id="vid-canvas"></div>
      </div>
```

> javascript

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
       window.addEventListener("load", function(){
       // [1] GET ALL THE HTML ELEMENTS
       var video = document.getElementById("vid-show"),
           canvas = document.getElementById("vid-canvas"),
           take = document.getElementById("vid-take");
       // [2] ASK FOR USER PERMISSION TO ACCESS CAMERA
       // WILL FAIL IF NO CAMERA IS ATTACHED TO COMPUTER
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } 
       })
       .then(function(stream) {
       // [3] SHOW VIDEO STREAM ON VIDEO TAG
       video.srcObject = stream;
       video.play();

       // [4] WHEN WE CLICK ON "TAKE PHOTO" BUTTON
       take.addEventListener("click", function(){
       // Create snapshot from video
       var draw = document.createElement("canvas");
       draw.width = video.videoWidth;
       draw.height = video.videoHeight;
       var context2D = draw.getContext("2d");
       context2D.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
       // Put into canvas container
       canvas.innerHTML = "";
       canvas.appendChild(draw);
     });
  })
  </script>
```